# JQUery autocomplete in ASP.Net Webservice

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-autocomplete

This is driving me crazy , I just keep getting the message "error" nothing else. I had this autocomplete working with AJAX Toolkit, but I want to try JQuery, I have very little experience with JQuery.  Here is WebService code:

```
  [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
  [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
  // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
  [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
 public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

public WebService () {

    //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
    //InitializeComponent(); 
}

[WebMethod]
public static string GetNames(string prefixText, int count)
{
    Trie ArtistTrie = new Trie();
    if (HttpContext.Current.Cache["CustomersTrie"] == null)
    {          
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstring"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
        comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TopArtists ORDER BY name ASC";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();            
        da.SelectCommand = comm;
        comm.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();
        da.Fill(dt);
        conn.Close();
        Trie newtrie = new Trie();
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            // topartists.Add(dr[0].ToString());
            newtrie.Add(dr[0].ToString());
        }
        HttpContext.Current.Cache["CustomersTrie"] = newtrie;
    }
     ArtistTrie = (Trie)HttpContext.Current.Cache["CustomersTrie"];

     List<string> list = ArtistTrie.GetCompletionList(prefixText, 10);
     List<Band> list1 = new List<Band>();
     foreach (string a in list)
     {
         Band newband = new Band();
         newband.Name = a;
         list1.Add(newband);
     }
     string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list1, Formatting.Indented);
     return json;

}
```

Here is JQuery Code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
           $("#tb1").autocomplete({

        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "WebService.asmx/GetNames",
                data: request.term ,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
         });
        });
      }) 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for one, your jQuery code has errors, including a missing semicolon at the end and an unnecessary function wrapping the autocomplete, try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#tb1").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "WebService.asmx/GetNames",
                    data: request.term,
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

for the ajax part, the return need to be in array, string[]

sample code,

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string[] area(string prefixText)
    {
        List<string> listString = new List<string>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Initial Catalog=EMS;Server=S-CEMSDB01;User ID=sa;Password=sqltest"))
        {

            SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("select distinct eqp_location from EQUIPMENT where eqp_location like '" + prefixText + "%' order by eqp_location", con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    listString.Add((dr["eqp_location"].ToString()));

                    //c.FullName, serializer.Serialize(c))
                }
            }
            dr.Close();
            dr.Dispose();
            con.Close();
        }
        string[] str = listString.ToArray();
        return str;

    }
```